# Sanitizing a GET with filter_input and FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT

Tags: php, validation

I have a table with a primary key called ID. ID will be passed to the page like:

```
testpage.php?ID=123.
```

If I use:

```
$sanitized_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
```

can $sanitized_id be safely used in a query?

Comment: `--` would be allowed through. I'd rather cast it as an int: `$sanitized_id = (int) $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Why not use Parametrized queries and stop worrying about all this ?

Comment: You could use `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` instead of using a sanitisation filter; that would yield either `false` (or null) or a valid integer.

Comment: @Shankar, I don't see how only using a Parametrized query would be sufficient in this case. I still need the ID to be an integer. if ID=abc-12/3, it won't work.

Comment: @TimT It would work, the parameterised query will have the net effect of `ID=0`.

Comment: "I still need the ID to be an integer" has nothing to do with [[tag:sql-injection]] - thus I changed tag to more appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You're correct, this was more of a validation question and not a sql-injection question. Thanks for changing the tag for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's close to being ready. Although SQL injection should be prevented by means of prepared statements, one still may want to have URLS strict and clean. and for this purpose your code is not enough. For example, `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_IN`T doesn't remove minus signs.

Here's some code that I use. I pretty much just copy and pasted it from an existing project of mine. I just changed the ID and put in the echos.

```
if (empty($_GET['ID'])) {
    echo('ID is empty');
    exit;
}

$sanitized_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$sanitized_id = str_replace('-', '', $sanitized_id); //Get rid of any - signs
if (($sanitized_id != $_GET['ID']) || (strlen($sanitized_id) != strlen($_GET['ID']))) {
    //strlen catches if + signs are included, I'm really strict at what I allow on the URL
    echo('Invalid url');
    exit;
}

echo('The sanitized ID is: ' . $sanitized_id);
```

Comment: All this mess is just useless. PHP users are known for their habit of writing tons of code out of nowhere, but this one is just exemplary piece of useless work.

Comment: @Your, I agree that this is overkill for this situation. I actually thought about that last night. I think casting will probably be sufficient for his needs. One of the original tags for this question was sql-injection so even though it wasn't stated in the question, it was on his mind. I'm using some similar code on two of my pages that are getting hit hard by sql injection attempts. My apache log files are showing attempts of all types hitting these pages, including ones with randomly placed plus signs. continued...

Comment: continued... If one of these pages is expecting an integer and it gets anything else I'm considering it a malformed URL and I don't want to waste any further resources displaying the actual page. At the same time, I'm logging some information to make sure the URL isn't a legitimate request coming from some other page that needs to be fixed. So far, every malformed URL has been bogus. So in my case, the code isn't useless.

Comment: Still there are two distinct matters - input validation and sql injection protection. The point is, former one should never be used for the latter. It's all right to have strict input validation. some Search Engines will be jealous if you have one page accessible via many different urls. So, in terms of input validation your answer is all right. And after removing sql-injection tag it is not all right

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer, making it aimed to url validation

Comment: I like your edit and I agree that these are two distinct matters. Each one is important.

Answer (score 2):

There are two very simple ways to make sure an entry will be an integer :

Casting :

```
$myInt = (int) $_GET['ID'];
```

Using `intval()` :

```
$myInt = intval($_GET['ID']);
```

The `filter_input()` function has great filters, particulary for sanitizing emails, urls, or IP addresses, but really, using it to sanitize an integer is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sanitisation, I would recommend going further and perform validation:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
if ($id === null) {
    die("Die, evil request, die!");
}
// post: $id is a valid integer
```

On top of this, I would still go for [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) anyway; in this code it might be obvious that ID must be a valid integer, but once the database code gets separated further from the request handling you will want some reassurance.

Comment: _I really don't have an idea why good answers never gets upvoted ?_

Answer (score 1):

> can $sanitized_id be safely used in a query?

NO.

Whatever input validation should have nothing to do with "using data in the query".

In a sanely designed application these layers (input validation and database interaction) should be separated, and lay too far from each other. And database layer should know absolutely nothing of the data origin, source, nature or any validations.

Thus, no matter which validations you performed at the entry point, at database level you have to use prepared statements anyway.